# Eclipse Graphiti Spray Properties View Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, graphiti

I am a beginner on Graphiti and Spray and sort of a beginner on Eclipse as well. I'm making a graphical editor using Spray DSL and the problem I'm having is that the properties view is not getting activated no matter what I try. I have gone through the plugin.xml and the plugin_propertysections.xml files in detail and everything seems to be in order. I have checked out this resource already: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.graphiti.doc%2Fresources%2Fdocu%2Fgfw%2Fproperty-sheet.htm to no avail.

Everything for the properties view is implemented but it seems that somewhere something is not enabling it to be activated. I would be really thankful for some support for this.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The ContributorId for the "org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertyContributor" extension point did not match the ID in the "org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertyTabs" in the autogen plugin.xml. If anyone has a similar problem, carefully check the case and IDs. The answer lies in plugin.xml.